# which module we can for Electron POS application receipt print?

Tags: electron

Have been developing POS desktop application using Electron 4 and angular 7. Need to implement print for invoice/receipt. 
Electron has feature to print current page or create PDF and print the same. But, I need to pass the Raw data to print since we have predefined template for print sheet.
Please advance which module we can use to achieve this.

Comment: Are you using any Thermal Receipt Printer?

Comment: Yes.. I'm using Thermal Receipt printer.

Comment: Did you had to interface also a POS card terminal? Do you have any tip how to connect an electron to these devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the **node-thermal-printer** library for the thermal printing of any printer which accepts the **ESC/POS command**

It can be work both type of printers such as LAN or USB.

I have used this library for the **EPSON** and **Everycom** thermal printer with the Electron and it works well.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-thermal-printer.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks.. Could you please share sample code node-thermal-printer with ElectronJS.

Comment: They have added the sample code to their GitHub page https://github.com/Klemen1337/node-thermal-printer because there are too many commands. Let me if you find trouble while executing. Please if the answer is helpful and then tick a right, so it can be helpful to others as well.

Comment: node-thermal-printer is working as expected, But, It is not printing properly Thai or vietnamese characters. Getting '????' or some junk characters in results. If you have any idea please help.

Comment: Hi @RajJagani could you pls share printer options for Evercom

Answer (score 1):

Try using the package electron-pos-printer. `npm i electron-pos-printer`
. View the [documentation](https://github.com/Hubertformin/electron-pos-printer/blob/master/README.md)

**Demo**

```js
// In the main process
const {PosPrinter} = require("electron-pos-printer");
// or in render process
const {PosPrinter} = require('electron').remote.require("electron-pos-printer");

// each object in the data array accounts for a row or line
const print_data = [
    {
      type: 'image',                                       
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'assets/banner.png'),     // file path
      position: 'center',                                  // position of image: 'left' | 'center' | 'right'
      width: 60,                                           // width of image in px; default: auto
      height: 60,                                          // width of image in px; default: 50 or '50px'
   },
   {type: 'text', value: 'Sample text', style: 'text-align:center;font-weight: bold'},
   {type: 'text', value: 'Another text', style: 'color: #fff'},
   {type 'barCode', value: 'HB4587896', height: 12, width: 1, fontsize: 9},
   {type 'qrCode', value: 'https://google.com', height: 55, width: 55, style: 'margin: 10 20px 20 20px'}
];

// returns promise<any>
 PosPrinter.print(print_data, {
    printerName: 'XP-80C',
    preview: false,
    width: '170px',               //  width of content body
    margin: '0 0 0 0',            // margin of content body
    copies: 1,                   // The number of copies to print
  })
  .then(() => {
    // some code ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
   });
```

Comment: good but cannot open cash drawer electron-pos-printer

Comment: @LilianBideau were you able to find out if there is any way to make the electron app interact with the cash drawer?

Comment: Not really I just print html tag <p>Open Drawer at {{time}}</p> in order to open cash drawer @Helper

Comment: Oh so you were not able to implement that, is that the case? thanks for reverting back by the way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print directly to the serial port without installing a printer driver,
I recommand `escpos` package to you.

`serialport` [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport)
`escpos` [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/escpos)
`escpos-serialport` [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/escpos-serialport)

but, you need to think about the column alignment style part.

```js
// electron(main)
import { app, BrowserWindow, Menu, ipcMain } from "electron";
const SerialPort = require("serialport"); // <-- add
const escpos = require("escpos"); // <-- add
escpos.SerialPort = require("escpos-serialport"); // <-- add

...

const options = { encoding: "cp949", width: 32 }; // <-- your encoding
let port = 'COM1'; // <-- your serial port name
let baudRate = 9600; // <-- your serial port baud rate

const device = new escpos.SerialPort(port, { baudRate });
  const printer = new escpos.Printer(device, options);
  device.open(function (err: any) {
    console.log("serialport error", err);

    printer      
      .align("CT")
      .style("B")
      .size(0.1, 0.1)
      .text("RECEIPT") // <-- big Text
      .style("NORMAL")
      .size(0.01, 0.01) // <-- small Text
      .tableCustom([
        { text: "Left Column", align: "LEFT", width: 0.1 },
        { text: "Right Column", align: "RIGHT", width: 0.9 },
      ]) // <-- you need styling
      .drawLine()
      .text("Small Text")
      .drawLine()      
      .cut()
      .close();
  });
```